# Can the ratio from a ratio test be used to find the value of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say I find the ratio of a geometric series using the ratio test and the ratio is 3/4.

can I use a1 / 1 - r to evaluate the series?

Ex. Sum from 1 to infinity of 3^(k-1) / 4^(k+1)

Comment: The *limit* of the ratios cannot be used to compute the sum. However, knowledge of the limit of the ratios can be useful in *estimating* the "tail," that is, the error when you add up only the first $n$ terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current state, no it cannot.

You will require some algebraic manipulation first, since in order to determine $\displaystyle S_\infty$ using the given formula for Geometric Series, we must first have that both the numerator and denominator has the same exponent of $(k-1)$.

This can be done as follows:

\begin{align*}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3^{k-1}}{4^{k+1}} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3^{k-1}}{16(4)^{k-1}} \\ &=\frac{1}{16}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{3}{4})^{k-1} \\ &= \frac{1}{16}\bigg[\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{4}}\bigg] \\&= \frac{4}{16} \\ &= \frac{1}{4}\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

No, because you can multiply every term in the series by any number; the ratios will be exactly the same (assuming no division by $0$ is involved), but the limit can change to almost anything.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: As you can see from the other answer, though, with the ratio _and the first term_ you can evaluate the series.

Comment: ^Yep, because the Geometric series formula is just a function of the first term and the ratio.